# How to show screen display during phone call on HTC Wildfire?

Tags: settings, calls, screen, htc-wildfire

I have started using the HTC Wildfire, and have a small niggle with it.  When making a call, the screen blacks out to conserve power.  This makes it awkward when you have to enter a number i.e. for an automated phone call response.  Is there a setting to display the screen during a call?

Comment: I am having same problem with htc wildfire.  I have screen protector clear on. I wonder if that causes the problem. It only happens to me when I call a mobile noT landline. The screen goes blank and flicks on and off now and then. If I wAnt to end call can't have tp quickly press end when screen happens to go on, causing me to waste money ie might want to end the call quicker. I press the on, off botton and screen comes and goes, so as said quickly press end. Hope its not the protector as want to keep phone in good condition ie old phhones have value today.

Comment: i guess its the sensors...they sense if the phone is near ur cheek..in that case light goes off..if you remove it from ur cheek and hold it in ur hand the light comes back..its my understanding,..

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure about the Wildfire, but on my Desire HD when I take the phone from my face, the motion sensor detects it and re-awakens the screen automatically. I'm not sure if it's a setting, a Froyo feature, or maybe an HTC sense feature.

Comment: Not sure about the exact hardware doing this on the Wildfire, but this is often done with the "proximity sensor" that disables the screen when you put the screen up against your face to prevent your ear from pressing any buttons. You can often see this as a small round hole or mark hidden behind the fascia at the top of the screen.

Comment: This feature also works on Eclair.

Comment: I have a Wildfire and can confirm the behaviour is as for Andrew M's Desire.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [Screebl](http://www.keyeslabs.com/joomla/screebl) - a background service that monitors the phone's orientation, and based on that orientation decides when to allow the phone's power-saving features to operate.

There's a PRO version too that allows for integration with Locale amidst other extra features.

Also check out Shake Awake from Maplekey (in the market) - it allows you to wake the phone during a call with a shake.

I also think that pressing the HOME key should turn the screen on again. Try and let us know.

Answer (score 2):

In your phone dialer enter the following sequence:

```
*#*#7594#*#*
```

will show you Shutdown App configuration - you can choose to have the device power off directly instead of showing the menu for Airplane Mode / Power Off etc. when you long-press the power button. **There's also an option for keeping the LCD on during the duration of a call**.

Comment: Does not work on my Samsung Vibrant, still on 2.1 :(

Comment: Works on my Spica, also 2.1

Comment: To use the above configuration code so graciously provided by sparx does the phone need to be rooted?

Comment: Nope. Not that I think. But the best way is to try. My phone is rooted, so I can't verify, just speculate. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a longer screen timeout?

`Settings | Display | Screen timeout`

Comment: Al, thanks, but I have already increased the timeout to 2 minutes with no effect.  As soon as I take or make a call, the screen blacks out, and only displays briefly every 30 seconds. +1

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on Wildfire, but I am using HTC hero.

You could have a try to press the key (like home, return or anything) or press the optical mouse, then it back to the phone call screen, then you can press num key after pressing the lower left hand corner Bn from the UI.